# how to generalize an ticker in viewFinancials

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to save `C.f` (or `IBM.f`, or `APPL.f`) into a generic variable (e.g. `STOCK.F`) and then reuse the generic command like
`viewFinancials(STOCK.F, type = c("BS"), period = freq, subset = NULL)`.

In the following code, if I want to analyze a different stock, "IBM", I have to change all the ticker name,"C", to "IBM" in the codes.  I am trying to find a way to initialize a generic variable(such as 'Stock') at the beginning, so I can analyze different stock only by changing the assignment to the variable 'Stock'.

Something like:

```
Stock<-IBM;
```

`viewFinancials(STOCK.F, type = c("BS"), period = freq, subset = NULL)`.

The code is:

```
SP <- new.env()
library(quantmod)

tickers = c("C")
start.date = "2000-01-01"
end.date = "2017-01-16"

getSymbols(tickers, env = SP, src = "yahoo", 
    from = as.Date(start.date), to = as.Date(end.date))

stock.data = SP$C

getFinancials(tickers, env = SP, src = "google", auto.assign = TRUE) 

freq = "A" # for annual
viewFin(SP$C.f,type = c('IS'),period = freq,subset = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for Income Statements, right.  Try the script below.  Here are the big 3; Income Statement, Statement of Cash Flow, and Balance Sheet.

```
require(quantmod)
setwd("C:/your_path/Desktop/")
stocks <- c("AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO","CVX","DD","DIS")

# equityList <- read.csv("EquityList.csv", header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# names(equityList) <- c ("Ticker")

for (i in 1 : length(stocks)) {   
        temp<-getFinancials(stocks[i],src="google",auto.assign=FALSE)
        write.csv(temp$IS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Income_Statement(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$BS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Balance_Sheet(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$CF$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Cash_Flow(Annual).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$IS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Income_Statement(Quarterly).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$BS$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Balance_Sheet(Quaterly).csv",sep=""))
        write.csv(temp$CF$A,paste(stocks[i],"_Cash_Flow(Quaterly).csv",sep=""))
}
```